# SoapFault Unauthorized - Connecting to Purolator Webservices

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am getting intermittent "Unauthorized" error messages, when attempting to call an external web service.  When I get this message, if I continually reload the page, it will eventually work.

Has anyone ever encountered a similar problem?  Do you think it is a server issue?  I am kinda wondering if it is a bad load balanced server or something.

The web service is being called via HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your question.

The "401 Unauthorized" error can be caused by the following issues:

1. Wrong development / production key or wrong development / production password. Please double check that the credentials you are providing are the ones given by Purolator when you applied for the keys. If five consecutive requests are sent to the server with a wrong password, the key automatically gets locked. You will either have to apply for another key or contact Purolator to unlock your key. (Note there are special characters that are part of the passwords like ":", "$" etc, you might need to use single cotes or the escape character)
2. Pointing to the wrong server.
   If you are using the example codes on the Resource Center in your development stage, these are pointing to the production server. In order to fix this, you just need to add "DEV" (development) as a prefix for the location URL:
   For example in PHP: 'location' => "https://devwebservices.purolator.com/PWS/V1/ShippingDocuments/ShippingDocumentsService.asmx" (in this case for Shipping Documents Service)

To point to the Production server use: 'location' => "https://webservices.purolator.com/PWS/V1/ShippingDocuments/ShippingDocumentsService.asmx" (in this case for Shipping Documents Service)

Feel free to post any Purolator specific questions (web services) on our Technical Support Forum for a prompt response: http://purolatorwebservices.com

Thank you,
Purolator E-Ship Web Services Team
webservices@purolator.com

Comment: I would like to add that I am using the DEVWEBSERVICE.  There are no issues with the development servers at this time?  I am finding it very strange that resending the same request eventually makes it work.  It denied me about 3 times in a row as a maximum.  It always works after a few tries.

Comment: Checked out the forums.  Another person has posted the same issue as me.  Could you please confirm the servers are behaving normally?

Comment: Hi Jon, we are constantly using the development and production servers and no outages have been reported.

Comment: Feel free to send us an email at webservices@purolator.com with your username, dev key and perhaps a screenshot or samples of your code and we can look into it.

Comment: Could this happen if multiple requests are made in rapid succession?

Comment: Kind of a old question but I can't find how to set the credentials on the web service...